# How can I overcome the "error C2100: illegal indirection" when accessing the contents of a void* in VS2008

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I have a C application that I've created in VS2008. I am creating a mock creation function that overrides function references in a struct. However if I try and do this in a straight forward fashion with something like:

```
void *ptr = &(*env)->GetVersion;
*ptr = <address of new function>
```

then I get a "error C2100: illegal indirection" error as *ptr, when ptr is a void * seems to be a banned construct. I can get around it by using a int/long pointer as well, mapping that to the same address and modifying the contents of the long pointer:

```
*structOffsetPointer = &(*env)->GetVersion;
functionPointer = thisGetVersion;
structOffsetPointerAsLong = (long *)structOffsetPointer;
*structOffsetPointerAsLong = (long)functionPointer;
```

but I am concerned that using long or int pointers will cause problems if I switch between 32 and 64 bit environments.

So is there are easy way to disable this error? Assuming not, is either int or long 64 bits under win64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then how about:

```
void **ptr = (void **) &(*env)->GetVersion;
*ptr = <address of new function>
```

The right way to do this is to work with the type system, avoid all the casting and declare actual pointers to functions like:

```
typedef int (*fncPtr)(void);
fncPtr *ptr = &(*env)->GetVersion;
*ptr = NewFunction;
```

The above assumes GetVersion is of type fncPtr and NewFunction is declared as
    int NewFunction(void);

Comment: That works just great (with a slight mod of void **ptr = (void **)&(*env)->GetVersion;). That tidies up the code very nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When dereferencing a "void *", you are left with a "void" which is has no size (or really no type for that matter), so it doesn't know how to assign something to it. It is the same as:

```
void blah = 0xdeadbabe; // let's assume a 32-bit addressing system
```

To add to my own response and give a solution, I would give it the proper type of a pointer to a function of the type GetVersion is. If GetVersion that your "env" struct field is pointing to is:

```
int GetVersion();
```

then you want:

```
int (**ptr)() = &(*env)->GetVersion;
```

Comment: I had never really though of it like that before. I'd always viewed a void* as being a pointer to anything, rather than a pointer to nothing.

Comment: I updated with an actual solution. Technically "void *" is a pointer to anything, but to dereference it is a snake eating its own tail. :)

Comment: +1 for "When dereferencing a "void *", you are left with a "void" which is has no size (or really no type for that matter)"  Fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Last time I played with void* & C under visual studio, VS didn't play nicely. 
Here are some information datapoints:

A pointer is always the size of the system word(8/16/32/64)...(unless you have segmented memory, which I'm *assuming* you don't have). This is because it needs to point to anywhere in the memory space. For a *von Neumann* machine, a function pointer is going to be the same size as a data pointer, because data and code occupy the same memory space. This is not guaranteed under a *Harvard* architecture. I'm not familiar enough with Windows Vista to know if it programatically fakes out a Harvard architecture for security reasons.

I personally would *not* disable this error, just for the sake of letting the compiler do its job.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, to store the address of a function in a pointer you should simply not do the indirection.

However, you also talk about being worried about the size of an int type that you might store a pointer into (which generally is not something you want to do unless you have a really good reason to).

If you want to hold a pointer in an int type for some reason, then on Windows a `UINT_PTR` type (or `uintptr_t` from `stdint.h` if you have it) will hold most pointer types (I don't think it's necessarily large enough to hold some pointer-to-member types).

Comment: So basically a uint will be 32 bits on a 32 bit OS and 64 bits on a 64 bit OS? If so, then that is the best type for me to use I think.

Comment: Just to be clear - it's not `uint`.  It's `UINT_PTR` (or `uintptr_t`).  They are int types that are large enough to hold a pointer (so 32-bits on Win32 and 64-bits on Win64).